# Add a Value Type independed

Tags: c#, object, reflection

I have a Scriptable language, in which I can define different Script Elements. 
Now I want to include support for Mathematical Operators without having a explicit Type.

I think Code explains this better:

```
var ret = a + b;
```

where a and b are objects, but at runtime they are both of the same type (e.g. int, double, etc)...

How can I solve this, without specifying every Type?

Comment: Your question is *really* unclear. Is this meant to be in C#, or in your own language? Are you trying to make that valid C#, or are you implementing a scripting engine to execute this?

Comment: I see no explicit type in your code as long as object a implements + and will take an argument of type b, Bob is your mother's sister's brother

Comment: Look into `operator` keyword

Comment: I will have valid csharp code! a and b ar csharp varaibles of type object, so i can not add them, but in them is a typed wich can be added, but i know the type only at runtime....

Comment: What happens if you declare the variable as `dynamic` instead of `var`?

Comment: i think dynamic will be very slow, because it uses reflection...

Comment: Why do you think you can make it faster than *dynamic*?   You won't, the DLR was heavily optimized.  Static languages are of course faster, but that ship sailed when you wanted to create a scripting language that doesn't use types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now try it via

```
Expression.Add(...
```

I think this will work. I also get my Value of "a" by building a Property Get Expression...

Comment: Expression trees are statically typed. They are not made for dynamic binding scenarios. They will just reject two `object`'s as input.

Comment: Yes, but I know the Type at runtime, and I can use Expression(Constatnt, Type) where I can tell the Type... And I can cache the Expression, because the Type always stays the same! And my Parameter Expression has already the correct type...

Answer (score 1):

> a and b ar csharp varaibles of type object, so i can not add them, but in them is a typed wich can be added, but i know the type only at runtime

A perfect case for runtime binding:

```
dynamic ret = (dynamic)a + (dynamic)b;
```

This has about the same semantics as if `a` and `b` were statically typed with the exact runtime types.

Comment: He will want to use reflection manually and cache that, otherwise it will be VERY slow.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 the DLR does that already. It generates runtime code specialized for the types commonly seen. Performance concerns are not part of the question. I see no evidence this operation is a hot spot in his code.

Comment: It doesn't. try to benchmark dynamic code against cached reflected code and you will be amazed by the results.

Comment: Yeah you can go faster. DLR is still much faster than reflection. It's not too bad. Factor of 3 difference to static performance if there's only one runtime case according to my measurement. I'm talking of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/655200/122718

Comment: You need to use reflection only for the first time for each type which means it will basically be as fast as finding a method in a dictionary and invoking it normally which is almost as fast as normal method call.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 `dynamic` does that. If you don't believe me, look at the generated code with Reflector. Every dynamic operation calls a runtime-replacable delegate. The contents of the delegate are runtime specialized.